# Why does Grails 3.0.9 say it is recompiling my changed files and yet I don't see the changes in the browser?

Tags: grails, groovy

Why does Grails 3.0.9 say it is recompiling my changed files and yet I don't see the changes in the browser?

I created a hello world app in Grails using [the official tutorial](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.9/guide/gettingStarted.html#aHelloWorldExample). When I made a change to the hello world text rendered in HelloController.groovy, I got this message at the Grails console:

> grails> File
>   /home/oge/code/grails-demo/grails-app/controllers/grails/demo/HelloController.groovy
>   changed, recompiling..

However, refreshing the browser showed no changes. I had to stop the console (Ctrl-C) and then restart the app again with run-app in order for my changes to appear.

FYI Grails 2.5.0 automatically reloads once I change the source files.